# How to do JSON handler in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I want to get and parse json in django view.

Requst in template:

```
var values = {};
$("input[name^='param']").each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: page,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    data: $.toJSON(values),
    success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);

    }
});
```

In view:

```
import json
...
req = json.loads(request.body)
return HttpResponse(req)
```

It give me error:

> the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

What I do wrong?

Comment: Could you show the content of ***request.body*** in the **view** ?

Comment: {"param1":"fdgdf3","param2":"ggggg","param3":"","param4":""}

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most web framework consider string representation as utf-8, so bytes in Python 3 (like Django, and Pyramid). In python3 needs to decode('utf-8') for body in:

```
req = json.loads( request.body.decode('utf-8') )
```

Answer (score 5):

```
json_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

worked for me