# how to parse json data with ajax POST in Django view

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I'm trying to parse json data in django view. But I got a problem.

I'm using below code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        selected = $("#mySelect option:selected").text()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/test/jsontest/',
            data: {
                   'fruit': selected,
                  },
            success: function(result) {
                    document.write(result)
                    }
    });
  });
});
```

when the client side user change the value, ajax code send json data.
But server side view receive a data in forms with "fruit=apple".
I think it's not json data format. So, I have no idea how to parse the data.

I try to parse like below, But I got 500 Internal server error after calling json.dumps(data)

```
class JsonRead(View):
    template_name = 'MW_Etc/jsonpost.html'
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self,request):
        data = request.body
        logger.debug('json data received(%s)' % data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 8):

Do post JSON string like this.

`data: {'data': JSON.stringify({'fruit': selected})}`

and receive like

`data = json.loads(request.POST.get('data', ''))`

Comment: If he removed the single quotes like:`data: {fruit: selected}`, he would successfully do `fruit = json.loads(request.POST.get('fruit'))`

Answer (score 6):

You need to post the data as JSON string rather than a JavaScript object.

```
data: JSON.stringify({'fruit': selected})
```

should do. Also note that you'll then need to `json.loads` the data in Django to actually do anything with it.

Comment: as you mention, I add jsondata=json.loads(request.body). but I got 500 error.

Comment: Did you edit the JavaScript client side as well? Try logging the error to see what is wrong (`try: ... except Exception, e: logger.exception(e)`).

Comment: exception caused by "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'", how can I resolve this?

Comment: I've never encountered that myself, but maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968752/how-to-do-json-handler-in-django

Comment: json.loads( request.body.decode('utf-8') ) works for me!!