# Troubleshooting HTTP request and JSON message on Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, http, ubuntu

Okay, so I have been going at this for a while and it doesn't seem like I am getting anywhere. I am running a Django app with Nginx and uwsgi. I have an http.post and I am trying to even read the items which I keep getting errors for.

This is what my JS code looks like :

```
$scope.receipt_pay_update = function(items)
{ 

  response = confirm("Do you want to continue with the changes?");
if(!response){

  return;
  }
  var data = {
        'items': items,
        'time_now': moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    };
  items.showmessage = true;
  console.log(data)
       $http.post("/foodhub/dashboard/receipt_pay_modal_update", data,{
           data: JSON
       }).
       success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $scope.alertclass = 'alert-success';
        $scope.save_message_farmer = "Succcessfully update payment"
        console.log("SAVED!")
       }).
       error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $scope.alertclass = 'alert-danger';
        $scope.save_message_farmer= "Failed to update inventory, please try again"
       })
}
```

This is what my views.py looks like:

```
@login_required

def receipt_pay_modal_update(request):
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


data = json.loads(request.body)['items']

print data

rec = ReceiverActions.objets.get(identifier = data[0]['identifier'])

rec['paid_check'] = data[0]['paid_status']
rec['date_paid'] = data[0]['paid_date']

rec.save()
return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

1. I got an error of unable to decode JSON. So I tried `data = request.body[0]` which also didn't work.
2. Is there any other way I could be testing small changes on my server without having to do the Git push, Git Pull, Python -m compileall ., etc? The reason I ask is because I was taught to do it this way by practice and I feel there is a better way.
3. Where can I check my `print data`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969583/8150371

Comment: I get   `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: try `print request.body` to see if the body is not empty

Comment: It seems to be empty. Unless I am doing something wrong. The `console.log(data)` right before I make the request has data.

Comment: there is some issue with your JS code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `data` I was getting was not JSON appropriate. I went back and changed the request to send data as a json and it worked perfectly.